# Unable to clone git repository in Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, egit, gerrit

I am unable to clone a repository in Eclipse. But yes I am able to clone the same through git bash.

I am getting an error with possible reasons as:

- Incorrect URL
- No network connection
- SSH is not configured properly.

My URL is correct and I am having proper network connection, though. As far as SSH is concerned, I am having the same set of keys in my local Windows folder, *Eclipse > SSH2* and my Gerrit SSH public keys.

I am really confused, that where I am missing out on this.

Comment: Do you see a related entry in the _Error Log_ view? If so, please post it.

Comment: I am getting this -

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: 

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException:

Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

Comment: An SSH authentication failure. Revise your SSH settings in _Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2_.Make sure the _SSH home_ is correct and the _Private Keys_ actually exist.

Comment: id_rsa file exists, but there is no such file as id_dsa.

Comment: Hi Rudiger, I am able to solve the issue. It was due to SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to SSH keys. I generated the new pair of keys from eclipse and mapped it to Gerrit. It is working for me now.

Thanks Rudiger for your help.